# How can I associate a custom file type with a custom executable?

Tags: application-development, mime-type, file-association

I have a custom file type, made a custom MIME type for it, associated an icon with it.  Now I want to open it with my custom executable. If I click `Open`I get a dialogue <kbd>Could not display ... There is no application installed for ... files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?</kbd> and on clicking `yes` a pop up including the `ubuntu software`icon <kbd>Additional MIME types required. An application is requesting additional file format support.</kbd>
Selecting `Open with another application`does not lead to a possibility to enter a custom command line.

My ubuntu is 18.04.  I have also a lubuntu 18.04 where this works like a charm.  I feel in ubuntu I have to deal with `ubuntu software` where I did not find a way to add my custom application.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a way to add my custom program to the list of  `All applications` in the part `Open with other application`.  I added a file myapp.desktop in folder `~/.local/share/applications`
with content :

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=path_to_my_icon
Name[en_US]=myapp
Exec=path_to_my_executable %F
Hidden=false
```

And then it is easy.
I wonder if there is a simpler method to get the same result.